# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string - dynamic SQL and openquery

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014, openquery

Code below is our stored procedure that is trying to populate log data into our data warehouse.  For the life of me I can't figure out why I'm getting this conversion error.    All timestamp columns are `datetime`.   I've tried a myriad of different amounts of quotes, conversions, etc.  I believe it is due to the `ImportDateTime` column but Im not sure.  Heavily edited the stored procedure for conciseness.

```
        DECLARE 
        @SQL                NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,@SQL1              NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,@SQL2              NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,@ErrorCode         INT
        ,@checkcount        BIGINT
        ,@rowcounter        BIGINT
        ,@maxrowcount       BIGINT
        ,@minTimeStamp      DATETIME2
        ,@DateCollected     DATETIME2
        ,@ImportDateTime    DATETIME
        ,@AssessorDeploymentTimestamp DATETIME2
        ,@OrderSystemDeploymentTimestamp DATETIME2




        SELECT 
        @checkcount = 0
        ,@rowcounter = 1
        ,@ImportDateTime = GETDATE();



        SELECT @SQL = N'
        INSERT INTO ' + @ToDatabase + '.dbo.Log
            (
            ImportDateTime
            ,ServerSource
            ,DatabaseSource
            ,Id
            ,[Type]
            ,UserName
            ,AppCode                        
            ,SubscriptionCode
            ,Duration
            ,ServiceNamespace
            ,ServiceName
            ,MethodName
            ,[Parameters]
            ,[Message]
            ,StackTrace
            ,Url
            ,UrlReferrer
            ,Browser
            ,BrowserVersion
            ,Platform
            ,[Timestamp]
            ,IpAddress
            ,EriAccountId
            )
            (
                SELECT
                ''' +  @ImportDateTime + '''
                ,''' +  @ServerSource + '''
                ,''' +  @DatabaseSource + '''
                ,Id
                ,[Type]
                ,UserName
                ,AppCode
                ,SubscriptionCode
                ,Duration
                ,ServiceNamespace
                ,ServiceName
                ,MethodName
                ,[Parameters]
                ,[Message]
                ,StackTrace
                ,Url
                ,UrlReferrer
                ,Browser
                ,BrowserVersion
                ,Platform
                ,[Timestamp]
                ,IpAddress
                ,EriAccountId
                FROM (
                    select
                    Id
                    ,[Type]
                    ,UserName
                    ,AppCode
                    ,SubscriptionCode
                    ,Duration
                    ,ServiceNamespace
                    ,ServiceName
                    ,MethodName
                    ,[Parameters]
                    ,[Message]
                    ,StackTrace
                    ,Url
                    ,UrlReferrer
                    ,Browser
                    ,BrowserVersion
                    ,Platform
                    ,[Timestamp]
                    ,IpAddress
                    ,EriAccountId   
                    from openquery([' + @ServerSource + '],
                        ''select 
                        Id
                        ,[Type]
                        ,UserName
                        ,AppCode
                        ,SubscriptionCode
                        ,Duration
                        ,ServiceNamespace
                        ,ServiceName
                        ,MethodName
                        ,[Parameters] = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),[Parameters])
                        ,[Message]
                        ,StackTrace
                        ,Url
                        ,UrlReferrer
                        ,Browser
                        ,BrowserVersion
                        ,Platform
                        ,[Timestamp]
                        ,IpAddress
                        ,EriAccountId           
                        FROM ' + @FromDatabase + '.dbo.[Log] WITH (NOLOCK)
                        WHERE URL LIKE ''http://online%'' AND TimeStamp > ''' + @AssessorDeploymentTimestamp + ''' AND TimeStamp > ''' +  @DateCollected + ''' '') o
                        WHERE NOT EXISTS 
                            (SELECT 1
                            FROM ' + @ToDatabase + '.dbo.Log b 
                            WHERE b.id = o.id
                            AND CONVERT(DATETIME2, b.TimeStamp) > ''' +  @DateCollected + '''
                            AND b.ServerSource = ''' +  @ServerSource + '''
                            )

                    ) a
            )'
```

Here is the error message output -

```
Msg 241, Sev 16, State 1, Line 197 : Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. [SQLSTATE 22007]
Msg 0, Sev 16, State 1, Line 94 :       SELECT          MAX(CONVERT(DATETIME2,TimeStamp))       , NULL          , NULL          FROM AssessorLogDW.dbo.[Log]        WHERE ServerSource = 'AOR-AOSQL01'          AND DatabaseSource = '2018Q402'         ;        [SQLSTATE 01000]
Msg 0, Sev 16, State 1, Line 111 : 2018-11-08 00:48:12.8830000 [SQLSTATE 01000]
Msg 0, Sev 16, State 1, Line 136 : SELECT min(CONVERT(DATE,TimeStamp)),count(a.id),count(a.id)  FROM    (SELECT id, TimeStamp = CONVERT(DATE,TimeStamp)     FROM openquery([AOR-AOSQL01],   'select     Id, TimeStamp = CONVERT(DATE,TimeStamp)     FROM [AOR-AOSQL01].[AssessorLog2018Q402].[dbo].[Log] WITH (NOLOCK)      WHERE CONVERT(DATE,TimeStamp) > ''2018-11-04 00:48:12.8830000''')       ) a [SQLSTATE 01000]
Msg 0, Sev 16, State 1, Line 167 : @checkcount [SQLSTATE 01000]
Msg 0, Sev 16, State 1, Line 168 : 1161246 [SQLSTATE 01000]
Msg 0, Sev 16, State 1, Line 169 : @maxrowcount [SQLSTATE 01000]
Msg 0, Sev 16, State 1, Line 170 : 1161246 [SQLSTATE 01000]
Msg 0, Sev 16, State 1, Line 171 : @minTimeStamp [SQLSTATE 01000]
Msg 0, Sev 16, State 1, Line 172 : 2018-11-05 00:00:00.0000000 [SQLSTATE 01000]
Msg 0, Sev 16, State 1, Line 178 : 2018-10-26 15:05:43.5400000 [SQLSTATE 01000]
Msg 0, Sev 16, State 1, Line 179 : 2018-10-26 14:37:43.8300000 [SQLSTATE 01000]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Without having time to look through your whole code (maybe get it down to 2 or 3 lines that show the exact problem without the surrounding stuff), it depends on your language settings.
What always works is 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss(.sss)'

Answer (score 1):

This has resolved my problem. The `ImportDateTime` needed to be converted as well as my `Timestamp`'s and `@DateCollected`

```
  SELECT @SQL = N'
    INSERT INTO ' + @ToDatabase + '.dbo.Log
        (
        ImportDateTime
        ,ServerSource
        ,DatabaseSource
        ,Id
        ,[Type]
        ,UserName
        ,AppCode                        
        ,SubscriptionCode
        ,Duration
        ,ServiceNamespace
        ,ServiceName
        ,MethodName
        ,[Parameters]
        ,[Message]
        ,StackTrace
        ,Url
        ,UrlReferrer
        ,Browser
        ,BrowserVersion
        ,Platform
        ,[Timestamp]
        ,IpAddress
        ,EriAccountId
        )
        (
            SELECT
            ''' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),@ImportDateTime) + '''
            ,''' +  @ServerSource + '''
            ,''' +  @DatabaseSource + '''
            ,Id
            ,[Type]
            ,UserName
            ,AppCode
            ,SubscriptionCode
            ,Duration
            ,ServiceNamespace
            ,ServiceName
            ,MethodName
            ,[Parameters]
            ,[Message]
            ,StackTrace
            ,Url
            ,UrlReferrer
            ,Browser
            ,BrowserVersion
            ,Platform
            ,[Timestamp]
            ,IpAddress
            ,EriAccountId
            FROM (
                select
                Id
                ,[Type]
                ,UserName
                ,AppCode
                ,SubscriptionCode
                ,Duration
                ,ServiceNamespace
                ,ServiceName
                ,MethodName
                ,[Parameters]
                ,[Message]
                ,StackTrace
                ,Url
                ,UrlReferrer
                ,Browser
                ,BrowserVersion
                ,Platform
                ,[Timestamp]
                ,IpAddress
                ,EriAccountId
                '
        SELECT @SQL2 = N'       
                from openquery([' + @ServerSource + '],
                    ''select 
                    Id
                    ,[Type]
                    ,UserName
                    ,AppCode
                    ,SubscriptionCode
                    ,Duration
                    ,ServiceNamespace
                    ,ServiceName
                    ,MethodName
                    ,[Parameters] = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),[Parameters])
                    ,[Message]
                    ,StackTrace
                    ,Url
                    ,UrlReferrer
                    ,Browser
                    ,BrowserVersion
                    ,Platform
                    ,[Timestamp]
                    ,IpAddress
                    ,EriAccountId           
                    FROM ' + @FromDatabase + '.dbo.[Log] WITH (NOLOCK)
                    WHERE URL LIKE ''http://online%'' AND   CONVERT(DATETIME2, TimeStamp) > ''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),@AssessorDeploymentTimestamp) + ''' AND CONVERT(DATETIME2,TimeStamp) > ''' +  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),@DateCollected) + ''' '') o
                    WHERE NOT EXISTS 
                        (SELECT 1
                        FROM ' + @ToDatabase + '.dbo.Log b 
                        WHERE b.id = o.id
                        AND CONVERT(DATETIME2, b.TimeStamp) > ''' +  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),@DateCollected) + '''
                        AND b.ServerSource = ''' +  @ServerSource + '''
                        )
```